# text field listeners in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I am new to iPhone.

Basically I am from Java background.

What I need is when ever I change focus of one text field to another text field I need

to fire an event.

similar to focus change listener in Java.

What are the listeners available in iPhone and how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) methods like `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` which will be called when textfield becomes first responder.

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [**UITextField Class Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) tells you everything you need to know in the Notifications section:

### UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification

Notifies observers that an editing session began in a text field. The affected text field is stored in the object parameter of the notification. The userInfo dictionary is not used.

#### Availability

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

#### Declared In

UITextField.h

### UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification

Notifies observers that the text in a text field changed. The affected text field is stored in the object parameter of the notification.

#### Availability

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

#### Declared In

UITextField.h

### UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification

Notifies observers that the editing session ended for a text field. The affected text field is stored in the object parameter of the notification. The userInfo dictionary is not used.

#### Availability

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

#### Declared In

UITextField.h

**EDIT**

I realize that I should add the events you get from all controls, from Apple's [**UIControl Class Reference**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

### UIControlEventTouchDown

A touch-down event in the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat

A repeated touch-down event in the control; for this event the value of the UITouch tapCount method is greater than one.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchDragInside

An event where a finger is dragged inside the bounds of the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchDragOutside

An event where a finger is dragged just outside the bounds of the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchDragEnter

An event where a finger is dragged into the bounds of the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchDragExit

An event where a finger is dragged from within a control to outside its bounds.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchUpInside

A touch-up event in the control where the finger is inside the bounds of the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchUpOutside

A touch-up event in the control where the finger is outside the bounds of the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventTouchCancel

A system event canceling the current touches for the control.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventValueChanged

A touch dragging or otherwise manipulating a control, causing it to emit a series of different values.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventEditingDidBegin

A touch initiating an editing session in a UITextField object by entering its bounds.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventEditingChanged

A touch making an editing change in a UITextField objet.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventEditingDidEnd

A touch ending an editing session in a UITextField object by leaving its bounds.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

### UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit

A touch ending an editing session in a UITextField object.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared in UIControl.h.

You're probably most interested in `UIControlEventEditingDidBegin` and `UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit`.